# Unable to build Netbeans project

Tags: java, netbeans, build

Hi I'm trying to build a project for a assignment and I'm getting a error here

```
H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:993: The following error occurred while executing this line:
H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:837: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute
```

I have not found anyway of fixing this and would like to know what could be causeing this here is the whole output

```
ant -f H:\\NetBeansProjects\\JavaApplication3 clean jar`
init:

deps-clean:

Updating property file: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\built-clean.properties

Deleting directory H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build

clean:

init:

deps-jar:

Created dir: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build

Updating property file: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\built-jar.properties

Created dir: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes

Created dir: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\empty

Created dir: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output

Compiling 2 source files to H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes

compile:

Created dir: H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\dist

Copying 1 file to H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build

H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:993: The following error occurred while executing this line:

H:\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\nbproject\build-impl.xml:837: copylibs doesn't support the "excludeFromCopy" attribute

BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 4):

Check the answer in: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=231468

> I found a fix to this issue however I still have no idea why this happens. You must go to the build-impl.xml and on line 829 and remove the setting that says excludeFromCopy. This will them allow you to successfully compile your code. The resulting file is also runnable and accurate.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1:**
Install the later version of NetBeans. Or

**Solution 2:**
 If you do not want to install the later version of NetBeans, do the following changes to let the code compile

-Open \nbproject\build-impl.xml
-Find the lines containing 
-Delete the `excludeFromCopy` attribute from the above lines (not the entire row just the attribute), and now your code should be able to compile.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my impl.xml its line no 843 (Project/nbproject/impl.xml)

```
<copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" excludeFromCopy="${copylibs.excludes}" index="${jar.index}" indexMetaInf="${jar.index.metainf}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="@{manifest}" rebase="${copylibs.rebase}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">
```

change the above line as given below (removed [excludeFromCopy="${copylibs.excludes}"] part)

```
<copylibs compress="${jar.compress}" index="${jar.index}" indexMetaInf="${jar.index.metainf}" jarfile="${dist.jar}" manifest="@{manifest}" rebase="${copylibs.rebase}" runtimeclasspath="${run.classpath.without.build.classes.dir}">
```